# How to replicate mandatory requirement of server certificate on the REST API client system?

Tags: rest, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, tls1.3

I am developing a desktop client application for an https-protocol based REST API provided by a third party.

I want to test the programmatic communication with the API when the server's certificate is not installed on my local computer. For this, I need to know how to make it **mandatory** to have the server's computer installed on my computer. Note: the certificate is not self signed, rather it is issued by a CA.

I want to test what errors enterprise users will get when my client application will make the API call to the SSL server in a highly secure enterprise environment where the IT policy is configured to **mandatorily** require installation of server's certificate on the client's local computer.

Is there such a configuration in Window which makes it mandatory for server certificates installed on local computer, for any API communication? If yes, can someone guide me on the steps for Windows 10 Professional.

Comment: By default browsers and clients will throw an error for self-signed certificates that aren't known by the client. No configuration needed unless you explicitly opted out somehow.

Comment: Ok. But the certificates are issued by a Certifying Authority. These are not self signed.